# How to write code between onCreate and onStart?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Several times I've had problems writing code on `onCreate()`. Mostly because the `UI` has not been sized and laid out on the screen yet (even if I place my code at the end of the function). I've looked over the `activity life-cycle` to see if there's anything that runs after `onCreate()`. There is `onStart()`, but the problem is that `onRestart() recalls onStart()`, I don't want that. So `is there a way to write code between onCreate() and onStart()?` OR where should I write code that runs after the `UI` is placed and only runs once during its `process`?

Comment: What kind of code are you trying to write? Usually in onCreate you'd call constructors for your fields and in onStart you'd have some startup methods if you need any.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you need but you can "cheat" and simply store whether you have run code or not:

```
private boolean mInit = false;
void onStart() {
    if (!mInit) {
       mInit = true;
       // do one time init
    }
    // remaining regular onStart code
}
```

The other way of running code when UI is placed is to use the global layout listener:

```
public class FooActivity extends Activity implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_content);
        View content = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        content.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // unregister directly, just interested once.
        View content = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        content.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        // do things here.
    }
}
```